# Code in viewDidLoad not being executed

Tags: ios, xcode

In my storyboard User interface I have added some `UIImageViews` and `UIScrollViews`. I set the size and the position of these in the ViewdidLoad, in this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [facebookSharing setFrame:CGRectMake(400, facebookSharing.frame.origin.y, facebookSharing.frame.size.width, facebookSharing.frame.size.height)];
    [bumpImage setFrame:CGRectMake(500, bumpImage.frame.origin.y, bumpImage.frame.size.width, bumpImage.frame.size.height)];
}
```

The problem is that this code is not being applied. I have a button with the exact same code, and when I press it, it does work fine. So, is there the possibility that the code is not executed in the `ViewDidLoad`. (even if the `NSLog()` proves the `ViewDidLoad` is actually running)?

Furthermore, I have this code in the `ViewDidLoad` for a specific `UIViewController` for the iPad and the code works there. It works for iPad, but not for iPhone, in any controller. Why is this? Thank You.

Comment: You probably forgot to link your IBOutlets to your iPhone storyboard.

Comment: No, the outlets are there

Comment: I didn't mean to be offensive, it happens to all of us from time to time.

Comment: is this method getting called? check by breakpoint

Comment: I was supposed to add the code in the viewdidappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frames and bounds do not get set until viewDidAppear get called. Try moving this code to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: This is outright wrong. I invite you to `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: N Issues, it will call on ViewDidLoad.

Comment: @0x7fffffff, I struggled with this problem a bit and I think it has to do with the device you are using and possibly other things but the frames and bounds "could" sometimes be set by the time viewDidLoad is invoked and sometimes not (depends on ....) On the other hand, frames and bounds are guaranteed to have been set by the time "ViewDidAppear" has been called. And you want to put your code related to frames and bounds where it is guaranteed!

Comment: frames and bounds do get set earlier than viewDidAppear (in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`)

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the other answers, `viewDidLoad` is called too early for this kind of task.
`viewDidAppear` could be too late for Layout changes in general, though, as the changes there aren't considered for eventual animations anymore.

I like doing layout stuff in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (if the view itself doesn't already handle subview layout via autoSize/autoLayout/layoutSubviews/..)

This might be helpful:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH13-SW2

Answer (score -1):

After providing `IBOutlets` it must be property synthasized. So hence we need to use

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
     [self.facebookSharing setFrame:CGRectMake(400, facebookSharing.frame.origin.y, facebookSharing.frame.size.width, facebookSharing.frame.size.height)];
     [self.bumpImage setFrame:CGRectMake(500, bumpImage.frame.origin.y, bumpImage.frame.size.width, bumpImage.frame.size.height)];
   }
```

Comment: adding the self doesn't make a difference